# JFrame stays white or gets displayed after long task

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

I cannot get my Progress Bar Window to work as i intended.
Currently I can produce two different situations:

**[1]** My Frame with the `progress bar` gets visible after a long task is executed. Thats not intended because the `progress bar` is there to show the current progress.

**[2]** My Frame pops up before this, said long task but stays completely blank, that means no components get drawn on it.

For **situation 1** I used this (cryptic code):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Initialise and draw my JFrame here
    }
  });
```

For **situation 2** i used this

```
// Initialise without going into Event Dispatch Thread, that means without calling invokeLater();
```

to update the JFrame i used this `SwingWorker` in both situation

```
SwingWorker<Void,Integer> sw = new SwingWorker<Void,Integer>(){

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // do long task here and use setProgress() to activate Property Change
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> chunks){
    System.out.println(chunks);
}

};

sw.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
        if("progress".equals(arg0.getPropertyName())){
            // update Components on Jframe with arg0.getNewValue();
        }
    }
});

sw.execute();
```

I want something like **situation 1**, but that my Components are Visible during the progress.
Calling invokeLater(); displays my Frame after the task and thats not intended

This is the whole source code I am working with:

```
private static JProgressBar progressBar = null;
private static JFrame convf = null;
private static MyConverter conv;
private static JLabel statuscounter;
private static JLabel currentfile;
private static GridBagConstraints c;
```

After labeling them i initialise them in my method used for the progress bar.

```
convf = new JFrame("Progress");
    convf.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.ipadx = 50;
    c.ipady = 10;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    convf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    statuscounter = new JLabel();
    convf.add(statuscounter, c);

    currentfile = new JLabel();
    c.gridx = 1;
    convf.add(currentfile, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    convf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, tempFiles.size());
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    convf.add(progressBar, c);
    convf.pack();
    convf.setVisible(true);
```

Some Variables are static because I need them in my `worker class`

Comment: `SwingUtilities` also has an `invokeAndWait(...)` method, maybe that is what you need.

Comment: I only get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread`

Comment: That is because you are already on the EDT.

Comment: If I was on the EDT the JFrame shouldnt be blank.

Comment: Then, how do you explain the error message `Cannot call invokeAndWait from the >>event dispatcher thread<<` ?

Comment: So you mean that its a problem with my JFrame? I used normal `GridBagLayout` to draw it.

Comment: It sounds like you are interfering with the EDT's rendering responsibility. The fact you're calling invokeLater from the EDT makes me question the flow of your program. With the code you are currently showing, there's not much we can do. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem

Comment: In addition to the advice of @VinceEmigh.. Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: I cant create a mcve of a program with ~ 1000 lines because I dont know which method goes into this `Event Dispatch Thread` and which not. I just called `Thread.currentThread()` to see which thread is active before `invokeLater()` and it says that its the `AWT-EventQueue-0` Thread, so no EDT

Comment: That is the event dispatch thread, Einstein.

Comment: *"I cant create a mcve .."*  "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: I was calling this method from a `DnD Event`. This event seems to have `EDT` as its running thread, which makes sense. By wrapping this method, which was called in the DnD Event, to run in another `Thread` i got this working nice and smoothly.